# How to fix Notepad++ icons not showing?

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-office, notepad++, web-development

I like to develop in Notepad++, but ever since I installed MS Office 2010, even after setting it as the default editor for all html/php/js files, I still get the XML Editor's icon in the file browser, and not Notepad++'s.

I also would like to get rid of that XML Editor entirely, so if anyone can tell me what to change in *Add/Remove programs* to wash it off my system, I'd love to hear about it.

Comment: Did you try right-clicking an XML file / Open with / Choose default program, then selecting Notepad++ and ensuring the *Always use selected program* option was checked?

Comment: @Karan Yes. It does open with Notepad++, it's just the icon that's not changing.

Comment: Try resetting the ICON using the file Properties selection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file association is set correctly and only the icon needs to be changed, you can use something like [FileTypesMan](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html) to accomplish this.

1. Select the file type/extension you want to edit from the top pane:

   [image]
2. Next edit the selected file type (via right-click/context menu or <kbd>F2</kbd>) and ensure the **Default Icon** field is set to properly point to Notepad++'s executable (or whichever file contains the icons; perhaps a .DLL):

   [image]
3. Exit FileTypesMan, log off and log back in or reboot as required, then test your changes

Of course you can do all this from the registry as well, but this utility just makes it easier (and likely safer too). :)

Regarding removal of the Office XML Editor, I didn't find a separate entry under Add/Remove Programs for it, neither could I spot it when I chose to modify the Office 2010 installation and Add/Remove Features. Perhaps I somehow missed it. Anyway, no harm in it being there as long as it's no longer associated in any way with the .XML extension, which is what you want.)

---

**Edit:** The [Notepad++ File Association utility](http://blog.pcstarters.net/2011/07/notepad-file-association.html) might also be able to help, otherwise I would recommend trying again [via the program itself](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=File_Associations), or reinstalling so that the installer can set all default file associations properly.

Comment: You get a +1, but this will always have to be done every time I want to associate a new file type. I want to either remove it entirely, or change the icon for all future associations, dynamically.

Comment: I don't get it. *Why* will this have to be done every time? Normally when I change the default program associated with an extension, the icon changes to whatever that program uses. In this case obviously something went wrong and Notepad++ wasn't able to reset the icon. You shouldn't need to go down this route every time; normally the icon should be changed along with the default associated program.

Comment: This program you suggested edits the "File Type", not the icon of the bound program. Thus, I assume every file type has to be changed individually.

Comment: Err... Did you see step #2 above? The File Type Icon is *part* of the File Type Association, just that in this case they happened to get out of sync on your system for XML files. This program allows you to change everything, but you can simply edit the **Default Icon** field in your case and leave everything else untouched.

Comment: If you're still having problems with Notepad++ file associations, I found a specific [Notepad++ File Association](http://blog.pcstarters.net/2011/07/notepad-file-association.html) utility for you, but I've never used it myself. FWIW, [the official Notepad++ Wiki article on file associations](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=File_Associations) mentions FileTypesMan as the program of choice to fix possible issues, so no idea why it's not working for you. Perhaps something is overriding the change. It would be easy to confirm in the registry if you know how...

Comment: I think the problem was that I may have accidentally installed Notepad++ as I would install it on a portable USB device, and it didn't create the registry entries as it would've otherwise. Re-installed without portable option checked, and now it works. Edit your answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem this morning and found this question while searching the web on how to fix it. I tried this FileTypesMan tool which led me to solve it although the actual tool did not help. When I found the TypeName with the bad icon, I right clicked and followed the link to regedit. From there, it showed me a type called Notepad++_file, along with several others named things like Notepad++.cpp, Notepad++.h, etc. Now I don't really know where those other types came from compared to Notepad++_file, but I noticed for some reason Notepad++.c is the type that is actually associated with .c files on my system, as opposed to this catch-all Notepad++_file. And I also noticed a difference between them, there was a subkey under Notepad++_file called extShell, that the others did not have. I deleted this extShell key, rebooted, and it all works now.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well (though I'm on Windows 10). After reading @Rich's answer I decided to search for "notepad++" in Regedit and see what I could find. I spammed my way through with F3 for a while until I came across this key:

`Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Applications\notepad++.exe`

It contained a key called `ShellEx`, which itself contained a key called `IconHandler`. I decided I could safely delete the `notepad++.exe` key because I could just reinstall NPP if it broke things. Lo and behold, I only had to press F5 in Explorer for the Notepad++ icons to reappear. Then I just used Disk Cleanup to delete the thumbnail cache so that folder thumbnails regenerated.

I realise this isn't the ideal answer format but I'll post it anyway because I couldn't find this information anywhere else.

---

**Update:** It's happened again a couple more times in the past few months. Sometimes deleting the registry key isn't enough and I have to change the default program for the XMLs (or CSVs, or which file format is showing the incorrect icon) to some other program and then change it back again.