# Change DOCX icon

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-word-2010

I have a small (aesthetic) problem with my MS Word documents. After uninstalling a slew of programs (I don't remember them all) explorer no longer displays the correct icon on DOCX files (though it does for DOC files). Under the Type field in explorer the files are listed as "DOCX File"s, which, while technically accurate, is normally displayed as "Microsoft Word 2010 document." Also, the context menu no longer shows the "Open, Edit, New, Print" entries. I was able to get the documents to open in Word but am still having these aesthetic issues. I ran the fix as described [here](http://en.kioskea.net/forum/affich-282337-microsoft-word-icon-changed-to-unknown-program), and that fixed it for the office programs other than Word. I have also tried uninstalling and re-installing the entire office suite, but that also didn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried [running an Office Repair](http://helpdeskgeek.com/office-tips/repair-microsoft-office-2010/)?

Comment: @techie007 Yes I have.

Comment: Axel has identified the icon source below. Once you confirm it's the same for your PC (the {GUID} portion might be different), you can use [FileTypesMan](http://superuser.com/a/531551/138343) to edit/fix both the DOCX description and icon.

Comment: @Karan That did it for me!

Answer (score 0):

The icon for `Word 2010` is located in `wordicon.exe`

My registry settings under Windows 7:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\Windows\\Installer\\{91140000-0011-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}\\wordicon.exe,13"
```

The folder is hidden unless you persuade the Windows Explorer to show it.