# How can I restore the icon for MS Office 2010 Word?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word, icons

I am running windows 7 and due to some funny things that have happened with me attempting Ubuntu for a few months I have since lost its MS Office 2010 Word icon and now it appears as the generic icon.

Microsoft Office 2010 is still installed, and is working perfectly fine (including its component: Microsoft Office 2010 Word), what IS wrong is that its icon is missing on **Windows 7**.

Comment: You have a dangling modifier. What do you mean by ‘its’ when you say: “I have since lost its MS Office 2010 Word icon” Ubuntu, Office or Windows 7?

Comment: Is Word 2010 still installed? Do you have the folder group "Microsoft Office" when you go to start menu, All Programs? Do you see the Word 2010 icon in there? If so, try clicking on it to start it. If it starts, once in Word 2010, go to File, and then Open. Browse for any Word file, select it and click Open. Can you see the contents?

Comment: If you double-click that "generic" icon, what happens? I think you have a misconfigured file association problem here. Try the things I mentioned above and provide us with some more information.

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/592128

Answer (score 2):

For Windows 7 you can change the program an icon is associated with by:

`Start` > `default programs` > `Associate a file type or protocol with a program`

Scroll down to the icon you want to use, click it. Click `Change program` and select the program with which you want to associate that icon.

Answer (score 2):

Since you did not do anything specifically to cause this (such as messing with the registry, or the open with dialog) then I think the best option would probably be to do a repair on your installation of Office. Go to the Control Panel **>** Programs **>** Programs and Features, then select your installation of Office (e.g. Microsoft Office 2010 Professional Plus), then click on the Change button at the top, select Repair and Continue... This should restore the icon and any missing or corrupted files that may be required by Office.

See the [article](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/project-help/repair-office-programs-HA010357402.aspx) on office.microsoft.com/support for more detail.

Answer (score 1):

In start menu go to 
`Microsoft Office` > `Microsoft Office Tools` > `Microsoft Office Picture Manager` > `Help` > `Detect and Repair` check `restore my shortcuts while repairing` and press `Start`.